# How to upgrade the code to Django 2 or use something similar to "path" in Django 1.9?

Tags: python, django

I was using Django 1.9 and upgraded to Django 2.0 as follows:

```
pip install -U django
```

Check:

```
python3 -m django --version
> 2.1.7
```

The main reason to update django was the usage of `path`. As far as I understand, `path` is unavailable in Django 1.9.

So, I have this import in my code:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path     # !!! this line fails !!!
from django.contrib import admin
from my_tests import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("test", views.test_endpoint, name='test_endpoint')
]
```

However when I run the code, it throws the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.urls'
```

It looks like it is still using an old version of django.

How to solve this error? How should I upgrade to Django 2 or how can I use something similar to `path` in Django 1.9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it was done before Django 2:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^index/$', index_view, name='main-view'),
    url(r'^test/', test_view, name='test_endpoint'),
    url(r'^weblog/', include('blog.urls')),
    ...
]
```

Taken from [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urls/)

There was no path module thus it throws an error.

Besides I recommend updating to **Django 2.1** if it is not to much effort.

Here is a [guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/upgrade-version/) on how to do it. For version 2.1 you have to use one of the following python versions: 3.5, 3.6, 3.7. [Django-Python](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django)